# Display two charts with Google Charts API

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm working with the Google Charts API for a project and I'm having issues displaying multiple charts. I've modified my code a bunch based on what I've found, but I still cannot get my second chart to display. You can take a look at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfppfy67/) of what I'm working with and see that only the first chart comes up. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening or what I'm missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualizations);
function drawVisualizations() {
    var turbidityData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Date/Time', 'Turbidity'],['Jun 29, 2016 10:15 AM', 12],['Jun 29, 2016 10:30 AM', 11],['Jun 29, 2016 10:45 AM', 11]]);
    var hgData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Date/Time', 'HG'],['Jun 29, 2016 10:15 AM', 0.46],['Jun 29, 2016 10:30 AM', 0.46],['Jun 29, 2016 10:45 AM', 0.461]]);
    var turbidityOptions = { 
        title: 'SMC Turbidity (past 24 hours)',
        height: 800,
        width: 1000, 
        vAxis: {title: 'Turbidity'}, 
        hAxis: {title: 'Date/Time'}, 
        seriesType: 'bars', 
        series: {3: {type: 'area'}} };
    var hgOptions = { 
        title: 'HG Turbidity (past 24 hours)',
        height: 800,
        width: 1000, 
        vAxis: {title: 'HG'}, 
        hAxis: {title: 'Date/Time'}, 
        seriesType: 'bars', 
        series: {3: {type: 'area'}} };
    var turbidityChart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('turbidity_chart_div'));
    var hgChart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('hg_chart_div'));
    turbidityChart.draw(turbidityData, turbidityOptions);
    hgChart.draw(hgData, hgOptions);
}
</script>  
<div id="turbidity_chart_div"> 
<div id="hg_chart_div">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your divs

```
<div id="turbidity_chart_div"> </div>
<div id="hg_chart_div"> </div>
```

Comment: Gosh I have a case of the dumb today. Thanks for that!

Comment: Haha, no problem! We all have them.

Comment: If you could mark this as the answer, I'd greatly appreciate the rep!